# How to dissolve white dextrin in water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

Dextrin is labelled as highly soluble in water. I have white dextrin (analytical from Sigma Aldrich). When I mix it in water, no matter how long I stir and how little dextrin I put, I get a suspension. The dextrin does not dissolve.

I am not a "real" chemist. If I search on Google with keyword such as `dextrin water solution`, nothing pops up, except that dextrin is highly soluble in water.

I must miss something obvious. I just don't know what. If someone could point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 7):

Try **heating the water**.

Sugar is also very water soluble, but just dumping sugar into cold water is going to take forever to dissolve. You'll age before you get a clear solution. So, add heat and stir it, and it should dissolve.

PS: Some dextrins are only partially solvable. If sigma aldrich says that your particular dextrin is fully solvable, then it should be. Check the label.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: the darker the color of dextrin is, the better it's soluble in water. White dextrin is practically always only partially soluble in water, whereas yellow one is often fully miscible.

If the main goal is to get a homogeneous solution, use yellow dextrin. Yellow dextrin (the "burnt" one) is obtained by heating dry starch powder till the color changes to yellowish-brown. You can pretty much do the same by putting some potato starch on a sheet of paper lying in a baking tray at $\pu{120 .. 180 ^\circ C}$ in oven for a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try that this week as we just need a good dextrin solution.